# I want to lock the tab's orientation permanently for a application

Tags: android

I want to lock the orientation for a tab. I want the tab's orientation to be horizontal all the time. How can I achieve this?

Comment: supply some code how you build your tab. its easier to get you a decent solution then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try all your activity tags like this

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscap" >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your class,it will be called automatic :
//Can change from PORTRAIT  to landscape, this works inside tabs fragments

```
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser) {
        Activity a = getActivity();
        if(a != null) a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}
```

Comment: setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);  <--- it should be LANDSCAPE instead of PORTRAIT though :)